# Is GraphML compatible with GXL, GML, XGMML or SVG?

Tags: graphml, graph-modelling-language

The website http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/ lists the file formats GXL, GML, XGMML or SVG.
All of them, including graphML are considered to be "standards".
Unfortunately there is not really a huge amount of information listed on how they play together. Some links are even dead, most of the information was written down more than a decade ago.

I created some minimalist examples to see how the file formats work and I'd tend to think there should be a way to convert them. But until this point I haven't figured out any library or python-module which can do that. (networkx seems to do a good job, but is not perfect).

There's `pygraphml` but it doesn't look very official.

Has anyone who provided another new standard published some kind of converter?

Also I wonder how much they are even discussed. SO only has tags for GraphML, GML (Graph Modelling Language) and SVG (which is not only limited to graphs).

Comment: It's not clear to me what the question is here. What are you trying to do? These formats all have slightly different features, so there will always be _some_ kinds of data that is easily representable in one but not the other. The most basic use case, i.e. graphs with numeric edge and vertex attributes, should be supported by all. SVG is of course not a graph format, and IMO doesn't belong here.

Comment: @Szabolcs - I am aware of that, yet the website claims it's possible to convert one to another. Yet there is not code or anything provided